# JUnit and Mockito Dependencies for Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, build.gradle

I'm trying to use JUnit and Mockito in order to run unit tests on my spring boot project, but am having a hard time figuring out how to set up the dependencies in my build.gradle file for my gradle project. Here is the build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version '7.1.1'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

targetCompatibility = 1.11
sourceCompatibility = 1.11

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
    }
}

flyway {
    url = System.getenv('HW_DATABASE_URL')
    user = System.getenv('HW_DATABASE_USER')
    password = System.getenv('HW_DATABASE_PASSWORD')
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    implementation 'org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:3.0.8'
    implementation 'org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:3.0.8'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.9.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.4.9.Final'
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:5.2.1.RELEASE'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer:owasp-java-html-sanitizer:20190610.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.3'
    providedCompile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9'
    compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.7'
    compile 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:7.1.1'
    compile 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.2.32'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.6.48'
}
```

And right now I'm getting the error "Could not resolve org.mockito:mockito-core:3.6.48", where I don't even know if I'm downloading the correct Mockito folder from https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases. So as of now, none of my junit or mockito imports are being recognized. Any help there would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the version of Mockito not exist in the Maven Repository. The last version of Mockito is 3.6.28. Check in this page

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core

Comment: Yes this was the issue, thank you

Comment: If the information help to resolve your problem please mark the answer as correct. I don't have experience with Gradle, create a new question and post all the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the version of Mockito not exist in the Maven Repository. The last version of Mockito is 3.6.28. Check in this page [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core)